# css Hover Effect does not work in IE 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a hover effect  in css. It works correctly in all other browser except in ie6.

The problem is if I give a link then the hover works in that page but if I take href from the page hover doesn't works, please help me.

Comment: You could post the code for others to find out what's wrong and what needs to be changed!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `:hover` on anything not a link in IE 6.

Here is the quote from quirksmode:

> IE 5/6 supports both only on links. IE 7 supports :hover, but not
>   :active, on all elements.

You can find that [on this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Whatever:hover: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Answer (score 0):

Suckerfish is a tried-and-true IE6 fix for `:hover`

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/